# Download file from S3 to Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an AWS VM that runs a daily task and generates several files. I want my Rails app to download these files and place them in a folder within the app. Is there a gem or method in Ruby that can do this?

I know how to do it in bash with s3cmd and I guess I could create a script to get them this way, but looking for a more native rails way.

I am using the data in these files for the app, but I don't want the users to be able to download them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `aws-sdk` v2 gem provides a simple interface for downloading objects from Amazon S3.

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  access_key_id: '...',
  secret_access_key: '...'
)

s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key').get(response_target: '/path/to/file')
```

Comment: thanks. how do I actually run this? I just put this in a script in `lib/assets`. On the command line i've tried just using `ruby /path/to/file` `ruby runner /path/to/file` and I keep getting an `Access Denied` error.

Comment: also tried `bundle exec rails runner eval(File.read '/path/to/file')"`

Comment: I was able to execute it using `load path/to/file` and the file downloaded

Comment: You should be able to put that code in a custom rake task, and then run it via rake manually, or from cron or whatever scheduling system you like.

Comment: that's your file's name.

Answer (score 1):

> 

```
You can use download_file method provided by aws-sdk.
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  access_key_id: '...',
  secret_access_key: '...'
)
file_path = "file path name to download"
s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key').download_file(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is official Amazon AWS Ruby SDK: http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/

There is also an open source gem called Fog, that may be easier to use for simpler projects: http://fog.io/

Answer (score 0):

In the v1 `aws-sdk`, the code to download from s3 is...

```
File.open(local_file_path, "wb") do |file|
  s3_object(s3_key).read do |chunk|
    file.write(chunk)
  end
end
```