# How to use docx gem with amazon s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docx

I have this create action to extract data from doc and docx files using the docx gem and the msworddoc-extractor gem

```
   if @subject.save
    if @subject.odoc.present?
      @odoc_url = @subject.odoc.url
      if File.extname(URI.parse(@odoc_url).path) == ".docx"
        @subject.homework= ""
        doc = Docx::Document.open(@odoc_url)
        doc.paragraphs.each do |p|
          @subject.homework = @subject.homework+p.to_html
        end
      else
        MSWordDoc::Extractor.load(@odoc_url) do |doc|
          @subject.homework= doc.whole_contents
        end
      end
      @subject.save
    end
```

now, doc files works fine.. My problem is with `doc = Docx::Document.open(@odoc_url)` when i use the code on my local machine it works fine.. when i push into production i get an error `Zip::Error: File s3.amazonaws.com/~~~ not found` I'm not really sure how to load the file to be accessible to the docx gem

Comment: you most probably store the file in the filesystem in dev whereas in production, you store it in S3.  download the file first (try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179444/download-file-from-s3-to-rails-4-app) then save it locally then proceed with reading it.

Comment: Do i have to download it ? i mean msworddoc-extractor works fine without downloading the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally got it without having to download the file using open-uri

```
doc = Docx::Document.open(open(@odoc_url).path)
```